# My QThread finished but I cannot get the signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread

The run method of my **QThread** is finishing, but I cannot get the signal.

Here is the entire code:

My thread header:

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

#include "mydataobject.h"

class MyThread: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyThread(MyDataObject data,
             bool useData);

private:
    void run();

signals:
    void resultsReady(MyDataObject data);

private:
    MyDataObject data;
    bool useData;
};

#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

My thread code:

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread(MyDataObject data, bool useData)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->useData = useData;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    if( useData )
    {
        data.calculate(); // Do something
    }

    emit resultsReady(data);
    qDebug() << "Thread finished";
}
```

My test header:

```
#ifndef THREADTESTER_H
#define THREADTESTER_H

#include <QDebug>
#include "mythread.h"

class ThreadTester: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ThreadTester();
    void runTests();

public slots:
    void threadFinished(MyDataObject data);

private:
    MyDataObject data;
};

#endif // THREADTESTER_H
```

My test code:

```
#include "threadtester.h"

ThreadTester::ThreadTester(){}

void ThreadTester::runTests()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<MyDataObject>("MyDataObject");

    MyDataObject data;
    MyThread* thread = new MyThread(data, true);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(resultsReady(MyDataObject)),
            this, SLOT(threadFinished(MyDataObject)));

    thread->start();
    thread->wait();
}

void ThreadTester::threadFinished(MyDataObject data)
{
    qDebug() << "TEST";
    this->data = data;
}
```

Main function:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "threadtester.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ThreadTester threadTester;
    threadTester.runTests();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Why the public slot **threadFinished** is never called?

**Note**: the "Thread finished" message is appearing, but the "TEST" message not.

Comment: which qt version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put this information. Qt 5.3.2

Comment: I'm betting you do not have an event loop.

Comment: I suspect the same thing @MarekR just pointed out. Can you give a few more details about how you create the `ThreadTester`, perhaps also showing your `main()` if that's where you're creating all these things? Also, just out of curiosity, why are you using a `QWidget` base instead of a `QObject`? Is this actually a widget on a form (but you don't have the proper constructor for that, so...)?

Comment: Thanks @MarekR and JasonC. My mistake, this is not a QWidget. This is a QObject, I edited the question. I also added the main function code in the question. Sorry, I did not understand what you mean about "event loop".

Comment: @KelvinSalton Your code, as-is, with a dummy `MyDataObject` added to let it compile, works just fine for me with Qt 5.3.2 (as well as 4.8.1 with minor modifications). It prints both output messages.

Comment: This code works just fine.

Comment: However, it's worth noting that `ThreadTester`'s event loop isn't actually running while that thread is running, since you create it on the main thread, then `wait()` for the thread to finish in its constructor before allowing the program to move on to `a.exec()`. So what's actually happening is the signal's getting queued but not processed until `a.exec()` runs, which probably isn't what you're expecting.  See also https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Events_and_the_event_loop.

Comment: This is weird. Anyway, I will investigate what may be happening. If I find the solution I will post here. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code:

1. create `QApplication`
2. create `ThreadTester`
3. run method `ThreadTester::runTests` which does following:

   - creates tread object
   - connect to result
   - start thread
   - wait for thread…
   - now thread does it job and emits the signal
   - since you `connect` used default connection method, slot invocation is scheduled to be run in event loop which didn't start yet.
   - thread completes
   - …wait for thread completes (probably here you expecting final result, but look what happens later)
4. event loop is started
5. event loop executes queued invocation of slot `ThreadTester::threadFinished`
6. event loop waits for next events